# How to override the constructor of an extended class with a namespaced class (old-style constructor)?

Tags: php, constructor

Some PHP built-in classes use the old naming scheme for their constructor (I.E. their class name). `SoapVar`'s constructor for example is `Soapvar::SoapVar()`. Now I'm trying to extend that class and override its constructor. I have to use the class name to do that, the usual `__constructor()` doesn't work.

Non-namespaced, using `__constructor()`:

```
class SomeClass extends SoapVar {
  public function __constructor() {
    print "Trying to override parent's constructor.\n";
  }
}

$class = new SomeClass(); /* Not working */
```

Non-namespaced, using class name as constructor:

```
class SomeClass extends SoapVar {
  public function SomeClass() {
    print "Trying to override parent's constructor.\n";
  }
}

$class = new SomeClass(); /* Working */
```

Now I need to use a namespaced class. The only problem is this: [As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) So this:

```
namespace Example\Namespace;

class SomeClass extends \SoapVar {
  public function SomeClass() {
    print "Trying to override parent's constructor.\n";
  }
}

$class = new SomeClass(); /* Not working */
```

doesn't work! Is there any way to solve this or am I forced to use the global namespace? Is there a bug report somewhere for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facepalm**

Should be using `__construct()` and not `__constructor()`